# Order by query getting very slow in mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-order-by, query-performance

I have a simple query like as follows :

```
SELECT a.UserID, COUNT(1) NoOffriends
FROM UserMst a
LEFT JOIN UserFriends b on b.friendID = a.UserID
GROUP BY a.UserID 
ORDER BY 2 LIMIT 20;
```

above query has sufficient indexes and relations, still its performing very slow. It is taking 2 seconds, but when I remove "order by" clause from it, it is fetching results within 90 miliseconds. I have checked execution plan using EXPLAIN command, it's shows me 'Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort', How do I check further in it?

Answer (score 0):

From the doc:

> Temporary tables can be created under conditions such as these:
>
> If there is an ORDER BY clause and a different GROUP BY clause, or if the ORDER BY or 
>   GROUP BY contains columns from tables other than
>   the first table in the join queue, a temporary table is created.

Anytime a sort can’t be performed from an index, it’s a filesort. You can take a look [here](http://s.petrunia.net/blog/?p=24)

And since you're sorting using a computed field, Mysql has to compute every rows put that in a file and sort it to only retrieve the 20 firsts. Could be long if there's a lot of data.

Removing the `order by` Mysql just has to compute the 20 firsts results and give them back.

I don't have direct solution but to rethink the way you're retrieving this data.